# outDir not created when compiling TypeScript code in a Docker image

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm

I am trying to create a Docker image for a TypeScript application.

My **dockerfile** is the following

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./   

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run tsc

CMD [ "node", "dist/app.js" ]
```

It is a copy of the one suggestested by the Node documentation, with the only addition of

```
RUN npm run tsc
```

I build it with the command

```
docker build -t my-ts-docker-image .
```

and I run it with the command

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/app  my-ts-docker-image
```

Unfortunately though the exection generates an error

```
Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/app.js'
```

and the reason is that the compilation of the Typescript code does not created the `/usr/src/app/dist/` folder.

The `outDir` value of **typescript.json** has the value `dist`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true, //
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"]
}
```

and the `npm run tsc` command works perfectly on my machine when launched from the `$PWD` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Just for the sake of completion, this is the **package.json** file

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc -p .",
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.4"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `-v ...:/usr/src/app` option hides absolutely everything the Dockerfile does.  Delete that option.